# Is there a way to see workspace thumbnails all the time on secondary monitor on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: gnome, multiple-monitors, 20.04, workspaces

Have a dual monitor setup. One is smaller, with lower resolution, so I don't use it as much as my primary monitor. Is there an application or gnome extension for Ubuntu 20.04 which could be used to see workspace thumbnails all the time on secondary screen while using the primary screen for other things? A workaround would also be welcome (something like keeping workspaces-to-dock(WTD) extension with always show full setting on secondary monitor, with workspaces spanning across monitors. It would be nice to have workspaces set in a 2d grid. The WTD extension is not currently working on Ubuntu 20.04)